# How to dynamically set yaml settings by pod name

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I am trying to set terminationMessagePath dynamically to the name of the pod so that the file will not be overwritten on each termination. Is it possible to inject environment variables in yaml settings on startup of pods?

I have tried setting the YAML as /approot/log/termination-log_${HOSTNAME} and /approot/log/termination-log_$HOSTNAME but have not found a way to set this path dynamically.

Comment: Hi, you can use downward api to do this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/

Comment: Do you want to dynmically use podName or nodeName ?

Comment: I want to use pod name as it can be easily used as a unique identifier

Comment: If you can upload your yaml, I can get concrete context, nevertheless following example in the link might be useful for understanding your use case. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables

Comment: If it does or does not solve your issue, let me know :)